# Are the titled prayers/mantras in the Samhita parts of the Vedas self contained?

Tags: vedas, prayer, quote

Are the prayers/mantras in the Samhita parts of the Vedas self-contained or do they flow into each other? I'm mostly asking because the Vedas occasionally say "they said" and since Sanskrit has no speech marks it is ambiguous unless obvious from context when the speech ends. Self-contained prayers/mantras would mean the quotation has to end at the end of the prayer/mantra.

Comment: Can you give one illustration for better understanding? Thanks

Comment: @Pandya Basically a page on this: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01001.htm

Comment: ok. Let's discuss on [chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)